# iOS9 Safari Content-Blocker extension doesn't show on device

Tags: ios, safari, ios9

I am developing a Safari Content Blocker Extension for iOS.
The app is almost ready, perfectly working in simulator, but then I've finally found a real device running iOS 9 to test it.

And, don't know why, Content Blockers menu item doesn't appear on the device. Same build shows the menu item on Simulator, but doesn't show that menu on the device.

My Info.plist is pretty standard:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.Safari.content-blocker</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ActionRequestHandler</string>
</dict>
```

Tried adding TRUEPREDICATE, no effect. Tried other working examples from GitHub on the device, same result.

XCode 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o), iOS build 13A4325c both on the device and in simulator.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

```
Note: Apps containing content blocking extensions for Safari on iOS are available only on 64-bit devices, due to performance limitations of 32-bit devices.
```

4S and 5c simply doesn't show the Content Blockers menu item. Need to restrict app installation on arm64 only.

Comment: we have tested it on iPhone 6 but still not working on real device.